# API returned JSON data wrapped in a function, breaking json.loads

Tags: python, json, web-scraping

I'm trying to work with JSON data that is pulled from [USGS Earthquake API](http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/2.5_week.geojsonp). If you follow that link, you can see the raw JSON data.

The JSON looks great; however, the returned request is wrapped in an `eqfeed_callback();` that is breaking the JSON deserializer in Python.

A quick look at the code I have so far:

```py
import requests
import json
from pprint import pprint

URL = "http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/2.5_week.geojsonp"

response = requests.get(URL)

raw_json = str(response.content)
json = json.loads(raw_json)

print(json)
```

I get the errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run.py", line 11, in <module>
    json = json.loads(raw_json)
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\json\__init__.py", line 354, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\json\decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\json\decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Although I'm positive the issue is that it's wrapped in that function and the JSON decoder doesn't like it. So how would I go about removing the function wrapper to leave me with the clean JSON inside.

Comment: The file from URL is not correctly formatted JSON. Check out these examples: https://json.org/example.html. you may consider to split and reshape your request response before parsing it with json package of Python.

Comment: I think you're right, I was following a tutorial from Google on mapping earthquakes, but I think I just need to find my own way to call the API and receive the response that I can use properly instead of hacking away at it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the wrong URL.

JSON wrapped in a function call is JSONP, which is needed for getting around CORS when calling an API from web browsers.

The URL to get normal JSON is

```
URL = "http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/2.5_week.geojson"
```

Comment: Genius! Thank you, I didn't know what JSONP meant, I thought it was just some odd filename.